# SugarCRM - REST Login add variable to $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables, sugarcrm

I followed [this tutorial](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.5/70_API/Web_Services/40_Legacy_REST/SOAP_APIs/Examples/REST/PHP/Logging_In/) to implement a REST login to my Sugar installation. Now I want to add a variable to `$_SESSION` called `blowfish_password ($_SESSION['blowfish_password'])` during the login.

I did this in normal login adding `$_SESSION['blowfish_password'] = blowfishEncode('mykey', $password);` to SugarAuthenticate.php and works well.

But how can I replicate this when the login is executed do by REST?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see the method login within the [SugarWebServiceImplv4.php](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/blob/master/service/v4/SugarWebServiceImplv4.php) class

Bye.